# Generating foreign based query sets

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I currently have three models which is Service, Customers and Orders as shown below

```
class Customer(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email

class Services(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField(null=True)


class Order(models.Model):

    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL)
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, null=True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL)
```

As shown, the Order model has foreign keys from the Customer and Service models.

When I construct a query set from Service and Customer.

`Service.objects.all()`

Or

`Customer.objects.all()`

How can I receive the same results from accessing the query sets based on the orders model?

Currently I am creating query set as shown below

`Order.objects.all().values('service')`

And

`Order.objects.all().values('customer')`

However I am not quite receiving the same results if I were to do as

`Service.objects.all()`

Or

`Customer.objects.all()`

How can I have a query set based on the order model to receive the results from query set from the Service and Customer as shown above?

Comment: its not working, because when you're querying from `Order` model instance only the related objects of the other two model which are connected to this instance of `Order` model are targeted. you can not reach all instance of the other two melds this way.